# Adicionar valores em um array com javascript para update

Tags: php, javascript, array

Preciso fazer uma edição de usuários em PHP  + javascript, porém como sou leigo em javascript não sei como construir a função javascipt já que posso ter diferentes valores dentro do form.

Meu form ficou construído assim:

```
<form action="#" v-on:submit.prevent="save(item.id)" method="POST">
    foreach(configurations as config ){
        <label for="{{conf.key}}"> {{ conf.alias }}</label>
        <input v-model="" type="text" id="{{conf.key}}" name="" class="form-control"> 
    }
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Eu não estou sabendo como fazer a função javascript para receber 1 ou mais parametros do imput

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o atributo 'data' do input:

```
<form action="#" v-on:submit.prevent="save(item.id)" method="POST">
foreach(configurations as config ){
    <label for="{{conf.key}}"> {{ conf.alias }}</label>
    <input v-model="" type="text" id="{{conf.key}}" name="" class="form-control" data-param1="parametro1" data-param2="parametro2"> 
}
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Salvar</button>
```